# Unparsable Query when registering WMI event

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to register an event in WMI through powershell, however the query below keeps returning 'unparsable query' which I'm struggling to figure out. The folder is created already.

```
$Action = { New-Event "PowerShell.ProcessCreated" -Sender $Sender -EventArguments $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance }
Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE targetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND targetInstance.Path = 'E:\MyTestFolder'" -SourceIdentifier "ProcessStarted" -Action $Action
```

The event is to monitor a folder and the action for the event is to send a notification to the event viewer in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try the following syntax  (I use double \ in the path and doubles quotes):

```
$Action = { New-Event "PowerShell.ProcessCreated" -Sender $Sender -EventArguments $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance }
Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE TargetInstance ISA `"CIM_DataFile`" AND TargetInstance.Path=`"E:\\MyTestFolder`"" -SourceIdentifier "ProcessStarted" -Action $Action
```